# Dynamically iterate over static information

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Suppose I have some class specialized for each enum type:

```
enum MyEnum {
  EnumA = 0, EnumB, EnumSize
};

template <enum MyEnum> 
class StaticEnumInfo {

};

template <> 
class StaticEnumInfo<EnumA>{
  typedef bool type;
  const std::string name = "EnumA";
};

template <> 
class StaticEnumInfo<EnumB>{
  typedef int type;
  const std::string name = "EnumB";
};
```

Is it possible to iterate over all names and print them?
I want to write something like:

```
for(MyEnum i = EnumA; i < EnumSize; ++i){
    // Doesn't make sense, I know.
    std::cout << StaticEnumInfo<i>::name << std::endl;
}
```

I know I can create one map somewhere else to solve this kind of mapping (for the strings, not the types...)

I don't have access to boost

Comment: C++ does not yet have reflection.  If you search how to iterate an enum you'll get many examples of ways to work around the issue.

Comment: No You can't change run-time data into compile-time constants. A mapping "function" would be required, so might as well map to the names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until proper [expansion statements](https://wg21.link/p1306) are available, you could always do this:

```
template <typename T, T... S, typename F>
constexpr void for_sequence(std::integer_sequence<T, S...>, F&& f) {
    (static_cast<void>(f(std::integral_constant<T, S>{})), ...);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
for_sequence(
    std::make_integer_sequence<int, EnumSize>{},
    [&](auto i) {
        constexpr auto index = static_cast<MyEnum>(int{i});
        std::cout << StaticEnumInfo<index>::name << std::endl;
    }
);
```

However be careful, as it will only work if all enum member are sequential.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/UlrxS9)

Comment: are you sure template for will allow for a constexpr loop iterator, and not just `template for (auto i : std::make_index_sequence<EnumSize>{})` ?

Comment: it's would require to provide `get<I>` for index_sequence, that's why I ask about the template for that you present

Comment: @MasterID I added a link to the expansion statement proposal